# Can not import pipeline from transformers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, anaconda3

I have installed `pytorch` with `conda` and `transformers` with `pip`.

I can `import transformers` without a problem but when I try to `import pipeline from transformers` I get an exception:

```
from transformers import pipeline
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-69a9fd07ccac> in <module>
----> 1 from transformers import pipeline

ImportError: cannot import name 'pipeline' from 'transformers' (C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py)
```

This is a view of the directory where it searches for the **init**.py file:

[image]

What is causing the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check `transformers` version. Make sure you are on latest. Pipelines were introduced quite recently, you may have older version.

Comment: To be precise, the first pipeline popped up in 2.3, but IIRC a stable release was from version 2.5 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

It is [announced](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/releases) at the end of May that **spacy-transformers v0.6.0** is compatible with the **transformers v2.5.0**. So, if you planning to use spacy-transformers also, it will be better to use v2.5.0 for transformers instead of the latest version.

So, try;

`pip install transformers==2.5.0`

`pip install spacy-transformers==0.6.0`

and use 2 pre-trained models same time without any problem

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
**pip install transformers==4.11.3**
run this command in cmd
ref: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10277